# Filtering of console output in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, console

is it possible to filter the logging in the console output in eclipse. I would like the filter out log4j debugging statement from all output. tks.

Answer (score 10):

Grep Console Plugin can filter eclipse console output to a second view
http://marian.schedenig.name/projects/grep-console/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to filter out log4j output, then you should put a log4j.properties file in your classpath and change the root logger to only log at the info level.

This URL will provide much more info on the subject:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: i would like to do so dynamically.....meaniing with a click of a mouse show all log4j log....with another show only println....is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about changing it dynamically at runtime?  If so, you can reload the configuration at runtime, as detailed here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6.  You cannot display any messages that were previously missed.

Answer (score 1):

If it's all log4j, you can edit you log4j.properties and specify the lowest logging level. This is not Eclipse-specific. Here's an introduction to log4j configuration:

- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

and a couple more useful links:

- http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/log4jhelp.html
- http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/sample-log4j-properties-file/
- http://homepage.mac.com/kelleherk/iblog/C1837526061/E2136921646/index.html

I don't know what your log4j configuration looks like, but you can e.g. specify something like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

if you have a `stdout` appender.